# Creating a 3x3 grid that's responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate [trump.com](http://trump.com)'s landing page but as a 3x3 grid.

I want the second cell of the grid to be the first cell when the website is forced to be responsive.

How do I change the grid with media queries to be full width rectangles under each other and how do I make the 2nd cell on top with the first under it?

This is what I have so far:
https://codepen.io/pisoj1/pen/ZpdRMq

```
    .grid3x3 {
display: inline-block;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      position: relative;
    }
#overlay-content {

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.block {
  float: left;  
  top: 0;
  width: 33.3333%;
  height: 33.3333%;  
  position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 33.3333%;
height: 33.3333%;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #090909;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, your codpen link's broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `flex` and the `order` property, but if you need better browser support, here's my alternative:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,body,main{
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
}

div {
  padding: 16px
}

div:nth-of-type(1){background:#000;color:#fff}
div:nth-of-type(2){background:orange}
div:nth-of-type(3){background:mediumseagreen}
div:nth-of-type(4){background:purple}
div:nth-of-type(5){background:deepskyblue}
div:nth-of-type(6){background:lime}
div:nth-of-type(7){background:wheat}
div:nth-of-type(8){background:crimson}
div:nth-of-type(9){background:mediumblue}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html,body,main { height: 100%; }
  div {
    position: absolute;
  }
  div:nth-of-type(1),
  div:nth-of-type(2),
  div:nth-of-type(3) {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 66.6666%
  }
  div:nth-of-type(4),
  div:nth-of-type(5),
  div:nth-of-type(6) {
    top: 33.3333%;
    bottom: 33.3333%;
  }
  div:nth-of-type(7),
  div:nth-of-type(8),
  div:nth-of-type(9) {
    top: 66.6666%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  div:nth-of-type(2),
  div:nth-of-type(4),
  div:nth-of-type(7) {
    left: 0;
    right: 66.6666%
  }
  div:nth-of-type(3),
  div:nth-of-type(6),
  div:nth-of-type(9){
    right: 0;
    left: 66.6666%
  }
  div:nth-of-type(1),
  div:nth-of-type(5),
  div:nth-of-type(8) {
    left: 33.3333%;
    right: 33.3333%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>1 : Title/logo</div>
  <div>2 Expand to 768px to see grid</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</main>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/amdouglas/pen/bBNxdY)

Comment: Glad to help. Obviously you'll want to use some CSS classes instead of just using `div:nth-of-type(n)` to make it more manageable in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using display:flex for this

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">c1</div>

  <div class="item">c2</div>

  <div class="item">c3</div>

  <div class="item">c4</div>

  <div class="item">c5</div>

  <div class="item">c6</div>

  <div class="item">c7</div>
  <div class="item">c8</div>

  <div class="item">c9</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## Hello, **flexbox.**

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/8d4s4awL/2/) is my solution, based off Geeky's code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">c1</div>

  <div class="item">c2</div>

  <div class="item">c3</div>

  <div class="item">c4</div>

  <div class="item">c5</div>

  <div class="item">c6</div>

  <div class="item">c7</div>
  <div class="item">c8</div>

  <div class="item">c9</div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (minus aesthetics)

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  flex-basis:32%;
  flex-grow:1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
}
@media (max-width:400px) {
  .item {
    flex-basis:100%;
  }
  .item:nth-of-type(2) {
    order:-1;
  }
}
```

It ensures that your row of 3 items will always span the entire width, and moves your second item into the first position after the width goes below 400px. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. Very much appreciated. I like this solution more but the other has better browser support